# How to change spinner selection value by scrolling listview in android

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I want to change the value selection of a spinner when a listview is scroll by user. I have no idea how to do this any example would be a great help.

The spinner has list of item such as
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...

And the listview has verse number with a text

1. text in a listview
2. text in a listview
3. text in a listview
4. text in a listview
5. text in a listview

So, now when the listview is scroll, I want the spinner item number would change. When the listview has (2. text in a listview) at the top screen then spinner item would change to 2

Comment: Do you mean you have Spinner and you have ListView? And do you want to call Spinner.setSelection(int) when user click ListView item?

Comment: yes! i have edited my question you can check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you want to update your `Spinner` with the first visible item's position of the `ListView` while scrolling. So for that all you need to do is to implement `OnScrollListener` to your `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                  //Here You can get the first visible item position and can update the spinner respectively.
                  spinner.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);


            }
        });
```

You can see, when you implement OnScrollListener, you overrides two methods `onScrollStateChanged` and `onScroll`. And in `onScroll` method you get the firstVisibleItem's Position and hence you can update the `Spinner` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort

Comment: the code is working when I set the firstVisibleItem to textview like `setText(Integer.toString(firstVisibleItem));` but it's not working with spinner. When I did `spinner.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);` the spinner value is not changing not selecting based on `firstVisible`. Any idea?